# Avoiding redundancy in Composition pattern java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, composition

I have two classes A and B. Now, I have `B "has a" A` relationship. So, the most trivial thing to follow here is the Composition pattern. Now, one of the field of B is an object of A. The problem is some of the fields of A and B are common. So, in this case, those fields will be redundant. I can't create an abstract class out of the common fields and make A and B inherit it because they are already extending some abstract class. What would be the best practice in this case?

Comment: Are you saying that B may or may not have a A. And the fields are redundant only when B has a valid A?

Comment: B almost always has a corresponding A. Both have a common field, which is actually a file location, whose value is always same for both.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic. Is it almost always or always?

Comment: B always has a corresponding A :)

Comment: Then why not have the fields in A itself - and use delegate methods to make it look better for users of B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If A and B can't have a common base class, you can't put the common fields in such a class.

One way to avoid the redundancy is to create a third class C that contains the common fields of A and B, and let both A and B have a member of class C.

Such a re-factoring would make sense only if the common fields make sense as a separate class (i.e. that class would represent some real life object or concept and not just an arbitrary group of fields). Otherwise I'll keep the redundant fields.

For example, an `Office` and a `Person` probably wouldn't have a common base class (other than `Object`), but suppose both of them have properties such as street name, city, zip code, etc... You can easily see that these fields should be extracted to an `Address` class.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that your A and B class already extended with an abstract class, You can try delegate the common fields with a non common function to differentiate it

For example

```
class B extends AbstractB {
     private String myField;
     public String getMyField(){
           return myField;
     }
}

class A extends AbstractA {
     private String myField;
     private B b;
     public A(B b){
        this.b = b;
     }
     public String getMyField(){
           return myField;
     }
     public String getMyBField(){
           return b.myField;
     }
}
```